# How to create true unique number for each user ( session ? ) in php 5.2

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

Im new to php if I like to create true safe ( multithread safe ) unique number for each user 
when he create a file , the file name will be build from unique name , that i guess will construct from unique string. 
What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I assume using session_id() in combination with something like this does not help, does it: $token = trim( substr( sha1( uniqid( rand() ) ), 0, $len ) );

Comment: i change the question to its real meaning

Answer (score 0):

when the user access the page, is assigned to unique id, it is called session_id.
If you want to handle your `session_id`, you need to set it before `session_start()`. 
using »» `session_id()`

Take a look at the manual »» http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

Good Luck

Comment: And there's good reason why there's so much redundancy in the values generated by session_id() - if someone can predict the session identifier then you have no security.

Comment: And just to add....if you're trying to use the session identifier for managing transactions - do think about what's likely to happen with caching and multiple windows (i.e. sessions should ONLY be used for session data)

Comment: Can you give only one example of how someone can predict the session identifier?

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

If what you want is a number for each user, you'll want to have your database auto_increment (or if that isn't supported, do it manually) a unique ID.

If you want a unique ID for the session, and not the user specifically. Which you can then tie to the user after they log in. You can use PHP Sessions. The hash they use to select a user will produce a unique ID that isn't currently in use. Which is good enough. Then, when the user logs in, you add to the session the unique ID from the database.

Now your user and session are tied together.